# How can "this" be referenced/processed before the constructor has concluded?

Tags: java, constructor, this

The specific use where I thought of this problem is as follows, but it's much more generalized.

I have a custom `JFrame` class which also serves as an `ActionListener` for its components.  So my constructor looks something like the following:

```
private JButton myButton;

public MyCustomFrame() {
    super();
    myButton.addActionListener(this);
    // ... more stuff
}
```

My question is, how does this actually work behind the scenes?  If the constructor is what "creates" the object which is referenced by `this`, how can I use `this` before the constructor has returned?  The code compiles and works perfectly fine (as far as I can tell), so the object must already "exist" in some sense, but I'm concerned that this may cause unforeseen issues.  Is there any danger in passing a "partially constructed" reference to `addActionListener()` (or just performing any logic with it in general)?  Or is there some behind-the-curtain magic happening that keeps me safe?

For example, what about things which don't have default values and must be supplied by the constructor?  If I have `private final String SOME_VALUE;` declared, I understand that this should default to `null`, but the object isn't supposed to be fully formed until the constant is supplied a value within the constructor. So would the reference, despite being final, possibly have changing values?

Comment: Not directly connected to your question, but it may serve your purpose http://stackoverflow.com/a/3404369/2350145

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That Java Language Specification specifies the steps of [instance creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4)

> [...]
>
> Next, **space is allocated for the new class instance**. If there is
>   insufficient space to allocate the object, evaluation of the class
>   instance creation expression completes abruptly by throwing an
>   OutOfMemoryError.
>
> The new object contains new instances of all the fields declared in
>   the specified class type and all its superclasses. **As each new field
>   instance is created, it is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).**
>
> Next, the actual arguments to the constructor are evaluated,
>   left-to-right. If any of the argument evaluations completes abruptly,
>   any argument expressions to its right are not evaluated, and the class
>   instance creation expression completes abruptly for the same reason.
>
> Next, **the selected constructor of the specified class type is invoked.**
>   This results in invoking at least one constructor for each superclass
>   of the class type. This process can be directed by explicit
>   constructor invocation statements (§8.8) and is described in detail in
>   §12.5.

So by the time the constructor (which is a method) is invoked, your instance exists with default values.

For `final` fields, it appears those are defaulted as well if you try to access them. For example

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Driver();
    }

    final int value;

    public Driver() {
        print(this);
        value = 3;
    }

    static void print(Driver driver) {
        System.out.println(driver.value);
    }

}
```

will print 0. I'll be right back with the JLS entry if I can find it.

I couldn't find anything more specific then what is above. Maybe in [4.12.4. `final` Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A final variable may only be assigned to once.

You can take to mean that default initialization puts the value to 0 or `null` and the assignment changes it.

Comment: What about things which don't have default values and must be *supplied* by the constructor?  For example, if I have `private final String SOME_VALUE;` declared, I understand that this should default to `null`, but the object isn't supposed to be fully formed until the constant is supplied a value within the constructor.  So would the reference, despite being `final`, possibly have changing values?  (I'll add this to the question.)

Comment: @Jeff I tried to compile a program that releases `this` reference before assigning a `final` field and it was the default value (0 or `null`). There must be something in the JLS about this, I just have to find it.

Comment: I doubt the spec says anything about that as it is emergent behaviour. The field hasn't been assigned by the constructor yet as the constructor is code running in sequence as usual. You leak `this` before assigning any variable (final or not) and Java can't magically know what value you were going to put there.

Comment: @TimB Not magically, but I was thinking that there might be some compiler nonsense that perhaps rearranged the instructions, especially if you are populating it with a constant value like a String literal.  Interesting.

Comment: @Jeff If you try to use the `final` field in the constructor before you assign it, then yes, it would throw a compiler error. But if you leak the reference, it won't.

Comment: @Jeff I couldn't find anything. Maybe it's a question of interpretation. See my latest edit.

Answer (score 4):

Once you call your constructor, your object already exists from the start, and you're just populating it with values.

The danger of this comes if the method you're passing your object to tries to use a value that you haven't declared yet in your constructor.

---

You also want to avoid having your constructor(and other methods for that matter) behave in such a way that the user of the constructor wouldn't expect.

If the person instantiating your object doesn't have a reason to expect the constructor to automatically bind that object to a button, than maybe you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

`this` does actually exist before the constructor finishes.  However, allowing a reference to `this` to escape your object before the constructor is complete can present a danger.

What if you passed your `this` reference to a method that assumes your object is fully formed and ready to go?  Maybe this is fine in the case of your object, but in many cases, this could be dangerous.  Allowing other methods access to an object before it is ready to be used would present a serious threat to your program being able to run reliably.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right, that is a bad thing to do as `this` may only be partially initialized at the time you use it.

This is why many compilers will give a warning about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape this from the constructor because if another thread read variables of the instance which construction hasn't finished yet, the thread may read unexpected value.

A example is below.

```
public class A {
  private final int value;
  public A(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    new Thread(new Runnable() { // this escape implicitly
       public void run() {
         System.out.println(value);
       }
    }).start();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new A(10);
  }
}
```

This program may show a value other than 10 from Java Memory Model specification.